# Owl Carousel 2 jquery slider with different timeout values for each slide

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm using owl carousel 2 jQuery slider for rotate some ads in my site. I would like to have the ads displayed for different amount of time depending on the contents of the ads. Is there any way to achieve my requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: please share some relevant code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I am with @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: Hi Bhushan, I only tried with the default configurations. Following is the JS that I'm using. 'autoplayTimeout:1000' will be set to every slides.
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    lazyLoad: true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:1000,
});